# How to display things on toolbar icon (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to display text of the current video playback speed (playbackRate) on top of my toolbar icon.

Preferably, on any click anywhere on the page, I want the extension to get the current playback speed and display/update it on the toolbar icon.

How would you do this?

[image]

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

[browserAction.setBadgeText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/browserAction/setBadgeText) is used to set toolbar icon text but it shows up to to 3 characters (used to be 4 before).

```js
browser.browserAction.setBadgeText({text: '123'});
```